# Does addListener in JavaFX get garbage collected when the ChangeListener is typed as a lambda?

Tags: java, javafx, memory, garbage-collection, listener

I have realized that my project uses a lot of JavaFX `ChangeListeners` to keep track of certain conditions.

I am pretty sure that listeners do not get garbage collected when used with `property.addListener(ChangeListener)`, but if I put my listeners in lambda form instead of declaring them first, will they still not get garbage collected?

Example:

```
        field.focusedProperty().addListener((obs, oldVal, newVal) -> {
          // Do stuff
          }
        });
```

On a side note, do all the listeners get cleared when I close the program or do they continue to persist?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## Will the Listener be Garbage Collected?

A listener you register with an observable will not be garbage collected so long as it is registered with the observable. Assuming, of course, there's a strong reference to the observable. This is because the observable keeps a strong reference to each listener registered with it. In fact, this can be the cause of memory leaks in your application if you're not careful. That's why we have:

### Weak Listeners

To make your application more resistant to memory leaks you can use implementations of `WeakListener`. There are five public implementations provided for you:

1. `WeakInvalidationListener`
2. `WeakChangeListener`
3. `WeakListChangeListener`
4. `WeakSetChangeListener`
5. `WeakMapChangeListener`

These implementations wrap their corresponding listener and hold it in a `WeakReference`. That way the observable only has a strong reference to the weak listener and not the "real" listener. And that's why you have to keep a strong reference to the "real" listener yourself for as long as its needed, otherwise it will be garbage collected too soon.

#### Example

Here's an example of using a weak listener:

```java
import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.beans.value.WeakChangeListener;
import javafx.scene.Node;

public class Foo {
  
  // strong reference to "real" listener
  private final ChangeListener<Boolean> focusListener =
      (obs, oldVal, newVal) -> {
        // do something...
      };

  private final Node node;

  public Foo(Node node) {
    this.node = node;
    node.focusedProperty().addListener(new WeakChangeListener<>(focusListener));
  }
}
```

If you need to be able to remove the weak listener at will then you'll need to keep a reference to it as well.

#### When to use Weak Listeners

You should use a weak listener when you can't *guarantee* the listener will be removed when no longer needed. This is especially important if the listener captures a reference to other objects (e.g. the `Foo` instance in the above example).

Don't bother using a weak listener if the observable and listener are guaranteed to be garbage collected at relatively the same time. For example, if `Foo` had a property and adds a listener to said property itself (e.g. `this.someProperty().addListener((...) -> {...})`) then the property, and thus the listener, will be garbage collected when the `Foo` instance is garbage collected.

Also, using weak listeners may be more effort than they're worth if:

- Your application is trivial or relatively short-lived.
- Your application is relatively static (i.e. does not continuously create and throw away objects that you register listeners with).

If unsure, you can always go the non-weak route to start and only change to weak listeners if you profile a problem.

#### Event Handlers

Everything described here works the same for `EventHandler` and `WeakEventHandler`. Just note that the latter does not implement `WeakListener`.

### Lambda Expressions

Does using a lambda expression to implement a listener (or handler) change anything? Not in any way relevant to this context. A lambda expression is simply an implementation of a functional interface. An instance created via a lambda expression is just an instance like any other.

### What Happens When the Application Exits?

All memory allocated to the process is released back to the operating system when said process exits. That means all objects cease to exist in memory.

Comment: Thanks! Just as a follow-up, does a lambda representing a `ChangeListener` still count as a strong reference? I tried working with `WeakListener` but I couldn't figure out how to prevent it from being garbage collected before I could use it.

Comment: A lambda expression is simply an implementation of a functional interface. You get an instance of the interface just like any other instance.

Comment: Is it ok to have a number of regular (not weak) listeners that persist the entire time the program is open? I need them continually to update parts of the GUI each time the data changes. Do I need to store them all individually and remove them before exiting the program?

Comment: Yes, that explains everything! I didn't realize that listeners for a property get garbage collected along the object housing that property. Thanks again for the help!

Comment: How garbage collection works is deceptively simple in theory (it's the implementation that's complex). Basically there's a graph of object references created by the application. This graph has one or more roots (e.g. thread objects). The garbage collector traverses the graph and every object it _cannot_ reach is eligible for garbage collection. So a listener will be garbage collected along with the observable if, and only if, there are no other strong references to the listener. That's the case in the "Don't bother..." paragraph above.